# Access non-IP interface in docker container

Tags: docker

is it possible to access a non-IP network interface inside a docker-container? All docker (bridge etc.) networks seem to run with IP-addressing, but I want to access a CAN (`PF_CAN` = SocketCAN) interface `can0`.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to run your container with `--net=host`?

Comment: @Salem thanks, this works for me too.  However, is it possible to share only that specific CAN interface?  (if you set it `network mode` to `host`, then the container can't be connected to any other `networks`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Salem: I didn't know the `--net=host` parameter - It works! So in summary:

Run

```
$ docker run --net=host ...`
```

or use [Docker-Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networkmode):

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  foo:
    network_mode: host
    ...
```